# Redux reducer to remove an object from a list by name

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

Most of the examples I've seen regarding removing an item from a list use the index of the item in the list, for example:

```
case REMOVE:
  return [
    ...list.slice(0, action.index)
    ...list.slice(action.index + 1)
  ]
```

But if I want to dispatch an action that doesn't have access to the index of an item in a list, but only the name, how can I filter through a set of objects and only remove an object with `n` name?

Comment: are you using ES6/ES7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use findIndex() method if you are using ES6+ in order to find the index.

```
case REMOVE:
  let index = list.findIndex((x) => x.name === n); 
  return [
    ...list.slice(0, index),
    ...list.slice(index + 1)
  ]
```

Comment: Haven't run across `findIndex()` yet, this worked beautifully, thanks!

Answer (score 25):

An easier way would be to use the array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function

```
case REMOVE:
  return list.filter((item) => item.name !== n)
```